# Eliminate CORS in Angular2 and Solr5.5

Tags: solr, angular2-forms

I'm using Solr 5.5 to speed up the search for information in a news manager.
But when I try to send the url with the search parameters to Solr, the browser sends me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load '127.0.0.1:8983/solr/prueba/select?q=id:*&wt=json'.
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Origin 'localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Had you time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CORS on your Solr instance.

There are many options to do this, I will modify the Jetty configuration.

I found an interesting article, 
[Going Cross-Origin with Solr](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/03/26/going-cross-origin-with-solr/), that explain how to do this.